# If the limit of one function at $\infty$ is $\infty$ and the limit of another function at $\infty$ is $-\infty$ Then the limit of the sum exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on the interval $(0,\infty)$
If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -\infty$
 Must it be the case that $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)+g(x))$ exist?

I'm having hard time finding a counter example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $h(x)$ be any bounded function such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$$ does not exist. Then consider $f(x) = h(x) + x$ and $g = h(x) - x$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x$ so what's the limit of $f(x)+g(x)$ if

- $g(x)=-x+a,\;a\in\Bbb R$?
- $g(x)=-2x$?
- $g(x)=-\frac x2$?